# SQLite in-memory databases testing an EF Core application with temporal tables

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, xunit, temporal-tables

We are using system-versioned temporal table in our Entity Framework Core application. This works really well but we are experiencing problems when creating a test.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

I have been following this guide using SQLite in-memory databases to test an EF Core application from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sqlite#using-sqlite-in-memory-databases

The problem is that `Sqlite` will throw an exception for `SysStartTime`. This is expected since the property is marked as `prop.ValueGenerated = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate;` in `DbContext` and is normally handled by Sql Server. Is there anyway to make this work in SQLite?

> SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed:
> User.SysStartTime'.

[image]

User:

```
public class User : IEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime SysStartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime SysEndTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
}
```

xUnit Test:

```
public class QuestionUpdateTest: IDisposable
{
    private readonly DbConnection _connection;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context = null;
        
    public ChoiceSequencingQuestionUpdateTest()
    {
        var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                        .UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDatabase())
                        .Options;
                        
        _connection = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(dbContextOptions).Connection;

        _context = new ApplicationDbContext(dbContextOptions);
        
        _context.User.Add(new User()
        {
            ExternalId = "1"
        });

        _context.SaveChangesNoUser();
    }
    
    private static DbConnection CreateInMemoryDatabase()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");

        connection.Open();

        return connection;
    }

    public void Dispose() => _connection.Dispose();
    
    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public int SaveChangesNoUser()
{
    //Wont help since the property is marked as ValueGenerated
    foreach (var changedEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (changedEntity.Entity is IEntity entity)
        {
            switch (changedEntity.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entity.SysStartTime = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
        .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string)))
    {
        if (property.GetMaxLength() == null)
            property.SetMaxLength(256);
    }

    foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
        .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(DateTime)))
    {
        property.SetColumnType("datetime2(0)");
    }

    foreach (var et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach (var prop in et.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.Name == "SysStartTime" || prop.Name == "SysEndTime")
            {
                prop.ValueGenerated = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate;
            }
        }
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Migration:

```
public partial class Temporaltablesforallentities : Migration
{
    List<string> tablesToUpdate = new List<string>
        {
           "User",
        };

    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var table in tablesToUpdate)
        {
            string alterStatement = $@"ALTER TABLE [{table}] 
                ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime])";
            migrationBuilder.Sql(alterStatement);
            alterStatement = $@"ALTER TABLE [{table}] 
                SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = History.[{table}], DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON));";
            migrationBuilder.Sql(alterStatement);
        }
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var table in tablesToUpdate)
        {
            string alterStatement = $@"ALTER TABLE [{table}] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);";
            migrationBuilder.Sql(alterStatement);
            alterStatement = $@"ALTER TABLE [{table}] DROP PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME";
            migrationBuilder.Sql(alterStatement);
            alterStatement = $@"DROP TABLE History.[{table}]";
            migrationBuilder.Sql(alterStatement);
        }
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15#important-remarks-4

Comment: Does SQLite even support temporal tables?

Comment: If you vote down, please say why!

Comment: @MitchWheat Nope but I do not need to test that functionality, I simply need a value for `SysStartTime` and `SysEndTime` to prevent the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it like this in `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`:

```
foreach (var et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    foreach (var prop in et.GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.Name == "SysStartTime" || prop.Name == "SysEndTime")
        {
            if (Database.IsSqlServer())
            {
                prop.ValueGenerated = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate;
            }
            else
            {
                prop.SetDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing SysStartTime and SysEndTime from your models. You can add them using the following snippets:

Create a Constants.cs or similar:

```
        public const string AddSystemVersioningFormatString = @"
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[{0}] 
            ADD SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL 
                CONSTRAINT DF_{0}_SysStartTime DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),
                SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL 
                CONSTRAINT DF_{0}_SysEndTime DEFAULT CONVERT(datetime2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),
                PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[{0}] 
            SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (
                HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[{0}History],
                DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON )
        )";
        public const string RemoveSystemVersioningFormatString = @"
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[{0}] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[{0}] DROP PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[{0}] DROP CONSTRAINT DF_{0}_SysStartTime
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[{0}] DROP CONSTRAINT DF_{0}_SysEndTime
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[{0}] DROP COLUMN SysStartTime, SysEndTime
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[{0}History]
        ";
```

Then in your migration:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(string.Format(Constants.AddSystemVersioningFormatString, "User"));
```

So your models won't know about the extra columns, and you won't have to explicitly set anything in EF since SQL Server will handle all the setting for you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this slightly differently, first I added this method this method to my db context class (in a separate file):

```
    public void CheckIfUsingInMemoryDatabase(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (!Database.IsSqlServer())
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTemporalTable1>(b =>
            {
                b.Property<DateTime>("SysStartTime");
                b.Property<DateTime>("SysEndTime");
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTemporalTable2>(b =>
            {
                b.Property<DateTime>("SysStartTime");
                b.Property<DateTime>("SysEndTime");
            });
        }
    }
```

and then I just call it at the start of OnModelCreating:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        CheckIfUsingInMemoryDatabase(modelBuilder);

        ...
```

It was a little awkward for me as I'm scaffolding the database rather than using code-first, this way I only have to add one line to the generated context after each re-scaffold.